# detecting item with custom name and amount

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm wanting to detect a certain amount of a named entity, I have the majority of the command, but I cant figure out how to add the amount. Here's my current command.

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",tag:{display:{Name:"Enchanting Token"}}}]}
```

Comment: @Awesomedude Answers are not meant to be edited into question regardless of any kind of block

Answer (score 1):

You can use `testfor` to find players with an exact count in a single slot like so:

```
testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:26b,tag:{display:{Name:"Enchanting Token"}}}]}
```

If you want to detect items across multiple slots, or detect a minimum amount of items, you'll need to use command stats. Create a scoreboard objective `numItems`, then use

```
scoreboard players add @a numItems 0
stats entity @a set AffectedItems @s numItems
clear @a minecraft:gold_nugget -1 0 {display:{Name:"Enchanting Tokens"}}
stats entity @a clear AffectedItems
say Players with at least five Enchanting Tokens: @a[score_numItems_min=5]
```

Comment: Hey, poster here, another thing that i didn't think of is that this will limit the number scanned, is there anyway to add an or more to the count, like:

Count:26>b

Comment: See my second solution, which provides a way to do just that.